# spring junit test with two hibernate transactions

Tags: spring, unit-testing, transactions, junit

I have spring junit test consisting of two sequential transactions which are propagated as REQUIRES_NEW:

```
public class ContractServiceTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private PersistenceManagerHibernate persistenceManagerHibernate;

@Autowired
private ContractService contractService;

@Autowired
private EntityChangeService entityChangeService;

@Resource
private AddServiceService addService;

@Autowired
private ReferenceBookService refService;

@Autowired
private PropertyService propertyService;

@Autowired
private HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Test
public void testContractDeletes() {
    Long contractId = 1L;
    final Contract contract = createTestDetachedContract(contractId, PropertyServiceTest.createManaged(propertyService, refService), refService);
    ensureContractCreated(contract);
    deleteTransactional(contract);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, entityChangeService.findByPaginationOrderByUpdateDate(Contract.class.getName(), contract.getId().toString(), null, 0, 30).size());
}

@Test
@Ignore
public void testContractCreates() {
    Long contractId = 1L;
    final Contract contract = createTestDetachedContract(contractId, PropertyServiceTest.createManaged(propertyService, refService), refService);
    ensureContractDeleted(contract);
    createContractTransactional(contract);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, entityChangeService.findByPaginationOrderByUpdateDate(Contract.class.getName(), contract.getId().toString(), null, 0, 30).size());
}

private void ensureContractCreated(Contract contract) {
    if (persistenceManagerHibernate.isCreated(Contract.class, contract.getId())) {          
        return;
    }
    createContractTransactional(contract);
}

private void deleteTransactional(final Contract contract) {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.value());
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            try {
                contractService.delete(contract);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                toString();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}

private void createContractTransactional(final Contract contract) {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate2 = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate2.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.value());
    transactionTemplate2.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            contractService.create(contract);
            return null;
        }
    });
}

private void ensureContractDeleted(final Contract contract) {
    if (!persistenceManagerHibernate.isCreated(Contract.class, contract.getId())) {
        return;
    }
    deleteTransactional(contract);
}

public static Contract createTestDetachedContract(Long contractId, Property property, ReferenceBookService refService) {
    Contract contract1 = new Contract();
    contract1.setId(contractId);
    contract1.setName("test name");
    contract1.setProperty(property);
    contract1.setNumber("10");
    contract1.setType(refService.get(ContractType.class, 1L));
    contract1.setStatus(refService.get(ContractStatus.class, 1L));
    contract1.setCreated(new Date());
    contract1.setCurrencyRate(new BigDecimal(10));
    contract1.setInitialSum(new BigDecimal(10));
    contract1.setSum(new BigDecimal(10));
    return contract1;
}
}
```

Test freezes at commiting of transaction with insert sql statement, which is:

```
 private void createContractTransactional(final Contract contract) {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate2 = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate2.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.value());
    transactionTemplate2.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            contractService.create(contract);
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Why does that happening(debugger stops at some oracle code without source code provided) and how to write spring junit test with two sequential transactions correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the test is creating a deadlock on the Contract table in your database. The root cause of this is most likely the use of the `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation level, as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390888/differences-between-requires-new-and-nested-propagation-in-spring-transactions). The important part is this:

> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW starts a new, independent "inner" transaction for the given scope. This transaction will be committed or rolled back completely independent from the outer transaction, having its own isolation scope, its own set of locks, etc. The outer transaction will get suspended at the beginning of the inner one, and resumed once the inner one has completed

The `createContractTransactional` method is trying to insert into the Contract table but something earlier in the test must be holding a lock on it, I'm guessing it's the call to `persistenceManagerHibernate.isCreated(Contract.class, contract.getId())`. Whatever the cause, you have two independent transactions that are locking on the same table, i.e. a deadlock.

Try setting the propagation level the transactions in your test to `REQUIRED`, which is the default setting. This creates a new transaction if there isn't one already, otherwise the current transaction is used. That should make your test execute in a single transaction and so you shouldn't get a deadlock. Once that is working then you may want to read the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) on its propagation levels to make sure that `REQUIRED` is the right level for your needs.