# How to run two Spring transactions in a single hibernate Session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta

I know, that there is a way to descend to a low level - get connection and perform two transaction's by hand in a single hibernate session.

But the question is - *how to invoke second nested transaction in the same Session via @Transactional annotations (not using "low level hacks" or handwrited custom transaction management)?*

Some possible code:

```java
@Service
public class DoubleTransaction {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sf;

@Autowired
private NestedTeHandler nestedHandler;

@Transactional
void invokeTransaction() {
    Session cs = sf.getCurrentSession();
    Session nestedCs = nestedHandler.invokeNested(sf);
    System.out.println(cs == nestedCs);
}}

@Service
public class NestedTeHandler {

@Transactional
Session invokeNested(SessionFactory sf) {
    return sf.getCurrentSession();
}}
```

Comment: you could use transaction managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do that with

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
```

on `NestedTeHandler.invokeNested`. See documenation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html.

See also this question: [Differences between requires_new and nested propagation in Spring transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390888/differences-between-requires-new-and-nested-propagation-in-spring-transactions).

Comment: Can you please provide some confirmation, that nested transaction doesn't open new session ?

Comment: That's what the documentation implies. I have personally never used that feature so I can't confirm it.