# Spring transactions propagation level difference

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I want to actually understand the difference between `Propagation.NESTED` VS 
`Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.. My requirement is to save the `updateStudent` and `updateSchool` and to rollback the `updateBus` method where i made runtime exception purposefully. so i have used `Propagation.NESTED` and tested, which works fine, but the result is same with or without `Propagation.NESTED` in `updateBus` method, so what is the purpose of NESTED here.

On other note when i change my code like this without `updateStudentInner` method, entire transaction is roll backed. So here i don't understand the difference in keeping the Transactional level in `updateStudentInner` vs `updateStudentDetail`

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)              
public void updateStudentDetail(String name, int id) { 
updateStudent(name,id); 
updateSchool(name, id); 
updateBus(name, id);
}
```

Here is the entire code for this

```
package com.example.dao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class ExampleDaoImpl {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public void updateStudentDetail(String name, int id) {
            updateStudentInner(name, id);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateStudentInner(String name, int id) {
        updateStudent(name, id);
        updateSchool(name, id);
        updateBus(name, id);
    }

    public void updateStudent(String name, int id) {
        String query = "UPDATE STUDENT SET NAME=? WHERE ID=?";
        name = "Name " + name;
        int i = jdbcTemplate.update(query, name, id);
        System.out.println("i updateStudent-->" + i);
    }

    public void updateSchool(String name, int id) {
        name = "School " + name;
        String query = "UPDATE SCHOOL SET NAME=? WHERE ID=?";
        int i = jdbcTemplate.update(query, name, id);
        System.out.println("i updateSchool-->" + i);

    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    public void updateBus(String name, int id) {

        name = "Bus " + name;
        String query = "UPDATE BUS SET AME=? WHERE ID=?";
        int i = jdbcTemplate.update(query, name, id);
        System.out.println("i updateBUs-->" + i);

    }
}
```

Also it would be better is someone explain with realtime example of the difference between REQUIRE_NEW, REQUIRED, NESTED and where these to be used.

Comment: The `@Transactional` doesn't do anything in this case, because it is an internal method call. Spring AOP uses proxies by default and anything calling into the proxy will be intercepted, anything being called from inside won't.

Comment: Already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390888/differences-between-requires-new-and-nested-propagation-in-spring-transactions