# Can @Transactional method call another @Transactional method without suspending?

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I have method A and method B in different classes. Both are annotated with @Transactional. Method A is calling B. Is there any solution to call B in different transaction but without suspending A transaction? Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW on B gives the possibility to always create new transaction when it's called but is suspends the caller transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you can't do it with annotation REQUIRED_NEW.

But spring also support transaction manually with TransactionTemplate, TransactionDefinition.

we can use multiple definitions with just one PlatformTransactionManager.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management#4-custom-transaction-configurations

Comment: i think the problem may be in approach. Instead of trying to find how to call method in different transaction without suspending caller transaction i need to take out the method call from caller transaction

Comment: Yes, simplify the code is the best way, i just want to answer "can we call functionB without suspending transaction of functionA ...", it's possible ... but quite complicated then necessary

Answer (score 0):

Transaction propagation behaviour [Propagation.NESTED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NESTED) supports the requirement.

Do read through the Spring official documentation : [Understanding PROPAGATION_NESTED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-propagation-nested)

> PROPAGATION_NESTED uses a single physical transaction with multiple
> savepoints that it can roll back to. Such partial rollbacks let an
> inner transaction scope trigger a rollback for its scope, with the
> outer transaction being able to continue the physical transaction
> despite some operations having been rolled back.

Additional details on the nested propagation in Spring transactions can be read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12391308/4214241) as well.